# How do I output compressed CSS from Compass?

Tags: css, compression, sass, compass-sass

How do I configure compass to output smaller or compressed CSS files? I tried `compass -s compressed` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In your `config.rb` file:

```
output_style = :compressed
```

More at http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/.

Comment: Thanks, somehow missed that page in the wiki

Comment: The link works, it just points you to [a different url](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/)

Comment: Important thing to note: if Compass is already running while you're modifying your config.rb file, you have to restart Compass to execute the changes.

Answer (score 25):

Did  you try with the full name of the argument in command line ?

```
compass watch --output-style=compressed
```

Comment: that should read
    `compass watch --output-style=compressed`

Answer (score 9):

i use the following terminal command

```
compass compile -e production --force
```

reference: http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/production-css/