# Using Compass in Rails - config file not detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass-sass

I have just set up `compass-rails` in my Rails app and all works fine.

But it is using the default `:expanded` output and has debug line comments.

So by googling, I found out that the **Compass configuration** is placed at `config/compass.rb`

Here's my `config/compass.rb`:

```
project_type = :rails
project_path = RAILS_ROOT if defined?(RAILS_ROOT)

output_style = :nested
line_comments = false
```

But the output is still `:expanded` and has debug line, I have tried restarting the server many times but it still doesn't detect the config.

Any solution? Maybe the syntax is different?

Thanks

Comment: output_style = :compressed

Comment: Here is a dupclicate question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335920/how-do-i-output-compressed-css-from-compass

(or rather yours is duplicate xD)

Comment: @marczking Thanks you for the reply, bu that question is for general Compass usage, not under Rails

Comment: After few hours the output suddenly changed into nested. I'm not sure whether it's cache problem or something else. But it's solved!

Comment: okay I see. sry, didn't look so closely... glad you figured it out anyways :)

Comment: I had a similar problem. The thing is, that you need to change at least one of your *.scss files to force compass to re-compile the sass - otherwise your configuration changes will not be visible.